# How to change nginx default homepage to a static HTML website of my own?

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, dockerfile, containers

I have a very simple HTML called `index.html` file which generates a website along with some javascript and css.

In the same folder, there's a Dockerfile of my creation with the following lines :

```
# use nginx:alpine as base image
FROM nginx:alpine

# copy static website index.html into nginx default html folder
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html

# export port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx in the foreground
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The problem is that nginx default homepage **doesn't change** when I build and run my application :

```
$ docker build -t some-content-nginx .

$ docker run --name some-nginx -d some-content-nginx
```

I've tried a ton of things but I just can't seem to get my website to show up at the *localhost* URL.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last 10 hours trying to solve this and turns out it was a cache issue.

Solved it by clearing the cache for localhost using shift+ F5.